# Unity 2D spawn variables won't update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in my 2D sidescroller I wanted to set spawn points so that the player doesn't have to start at the beginning everytime.

But the variables won't update even so the player clearly activates the trigger (tested with debug.log)

This is in my playerController(PinkPlayerController)

```
public static float spawnX;
public static float spawnY;

void InstandDeath(){
        if(Health.gameLives > 1){
            Health.gameLives--;
            transform.position = new Vector2(spawnX, spawnY);
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(deathSound, transform.position, 10.0f);
        }
        else {
            youLose();
        }
    }
```

And this is in my spawner script

```
public float positionX;
public float positionY;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        //level1
        if (other.tag == "Player" && this.tag == "level1Spawn1"){
            PinkPlayerControler.spawnX = positionX;
            PinkPlayerControler.spawnY = positionY;
        }
        if (other.tag == "Player" && this.tag == "level1Spawn2"){
            PinkPlayerControler.spawnX = positionX;
            PinkPlayerControler.spawnY = positionY;
        }
        if (other.tag == "Player" && this.tag == "level1Spawn3"){
            Debug.Log("Spawner3");
            PinkPlayerControler.spawnX = 222.5f;
            PinkPlayerControler.spawnY = 15.0f;
        }
```

I just tried to hard code it in Spawner3 but this won't work either..

I checked the tags and they are all correct and there are no spelling mistakes so I have no idea why it won't update the values.

Thanks in advance :)

Chrizzly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
public class SpawnPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            var playerController = other.GetComponent<PinkPlayerControler>();
            playerControler.spawnPosition = transform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

To make a spawn point, create a gameobject with a collider (set to work as a trigger). Then add this script to the object. Then position the object in scene to where you want it to be.

Each time a "Player" tagged object triggers this spawn point, this Player's spawnPosition will be set to the spawn point's world position.

Comment: thanks that helped^^ the coordinates are updated but it seems like I made  a mistake in the controller script - can't I call it like this :  `transform.position = new Vector2(spawnPosition.x,spawnPosition.y);` in my death method?

Comment: You can do that. Though it's the same as writing `transform.position = spawnPosition;`. Unity automatically casts between Vector2 and Vector3. You can use Vector3 (or Vector2) for spawnPosition instead of two floats.

Comment: well the problem is that my player still respawns at the beginning of the level and I have no other transform.position in my script that could interfere with this call